# Converting from Lat Long Altitude to Geocentric to Topocentric using modern PROJ C++

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, proj, ecef, topocentric

I'm trying to use Proj to perform lat long alt to geocentric to topocentric transforms.

I've been able to do this fine in python, but the API pyproj uses underneath is apparently very old. I want to just use what the authors of proj apparently want me to use, which comes in `<proj.h>`. I'm having a hard time getting things to run correctly even for the base case.

```
#include <proj.h> 

int main(){
    auto proj_context = proj_context_create();
    double lat = 44;
    double lon = -78;
    double alt = 200; 
    
    auto lla_to_ecef_proj = proj_create(proj_context, "+proj=latlong +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 "
                                                          "+to +proj=geocentric");
    
    auto coord_4 = proj_trans(lla_to_ecef_proj, PJ_DIRECTION::PJ_FWD, PJ_COORD{lat,lon,alt,0});
    
    std::cout << coord_4.v[0] << std::endl; 
    std::cout << coord_4.v[1] << std::endl; 
    std::cout << coord_4.v[2] << std::endl; 

    proj_destroy(lla_to_ecef_proj);
    proj_context_destroy(proj_context);
    return 0; 
}
```

but all three values are infinity, so clearly that doesn't work.  I don't get warnings either. I've scoured the documentation, but it isn't even clear what a valid proj is or where to find such a list, let alone a comprehensive list of proper formats for projections arguments.

There also seems to be some sort of push in the API to change all transforms interms of coordinate reference systems?  But finding out what CRS code I need is damn near impossible, I don't know how to look those up properly with out "fishing".